# Twilio Room does not recognize connected participants

Tags: ios, swift, twilio-video

I'm using twilio as a service for a video chat app.
The room is will contain only 2 participants P1 & P2

**P1**

1. Gets a generated access token from the backend( with room grants added)
2. Gets the room name from the server
3. Connects to room

   ```
   let connectOptions = TVIConnectOptions.init(token: payload.twilioAccessToken) { (builder) in
       builder.roomName = payload.roomName
   }
   twilioLog("Will Connect to room with name \(String(describing: payload.roomName))")


   self.room = TwilioVideo.connect(with: connectOptions, delegate:self)
   ```
4. `func didConnect(to room: TVIRoom)` Called Successfully.

**P2**

1. Gets a different  generated access token from the backend( with room grants added)
2. Gets the same room name from the server
3. Connects to room

   ```
   let connectOptions = TVIConnectOptions.init(token: payload.twilioAccessToken) { (builder) in
       builder.roomName = payload.roomName
   }
   twilioLog("Will Connect to room with name \(String(describing: payload.roomName))")


   self.room = TwilioVideo.connect(with: connectOptions, delegate:self)
   ```
4. `func didConnect(to room: TVIRoom)` Called Successfully.

However, `func room(_ room: TVIRoom, participantDidConnect participant: TVIParticipant)` Never gets called.
Also, room.participants returns an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

1. If P2 joins the room when P2 is already in the room, you should be able to access P1 in `room.remoteParticipants`. Generally, you will want to set delegate for each participant to receive video, audio tracks from remote participants.
2. In this case, `participantDidConnect` will be called on P1 side.

Comment: Yes exactly what should happen, it's just that participantDidConnect is not being called & room.remoteParticipants is always 0

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that P1 & P2 had the same identifiers. They are treated as the same participant